# MouseX for a wave

Tags: processing

I'm new in Processing and I have a kind of easy question.

I have a `mouseX` added to a wave so on the left there's less wave than on the right. But on the right the wave is excessive. Do you know how to fix this?

```java
int wave = int(sin(frameCount * 0.02 + ( x * y ) * 0.01) * mouseX);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`sin()`](https://processing.org/reference/lerp_.html) returns a value in the range [-1.0, 1.0]. Define the height at the left (`h_left`) and the height at the right (`h_right`) and interpolate between the values by the function [`lerp()`](https://processing.org/reference/lerp_.html), according to the relative x coordinate of the mouse (`(float)mouseX/width`):

```java
float h_left  = 100.0;
float h_right = 200.0;
float weight  = (float)mouseX/width;

float height  = lerp(h_left, h_right, weight);

int wave = int(sin(frameCount * 0.02 + ( x * y ) * 0.01) * height/2.0);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked perfectly and I understand it now!